# Is there a way to enter number without showing them immediately?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I want to enter 10 numbers, and then show them in 1 line like this:
`1,4,5,2,456,23,...` and so on..

and it keeps writing them as I am entering them, and in the end when it's supposed to show all numbers in 1 line it shows only the last one.

I know it's possible with random numbers but when I enter them on my own I don't know how not to show them at all or keep them in 1 line and if it is even possible?

```
int a;
int x;
Console.WriteLine("a:");
a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
x = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're working with?

Comment: You can redirect input when running from shell prompt: `myApp.exe < inputFile`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok sure :) i'm new here, i'll try to be more specific in the future:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*i dont know how to write them at the end all in 1 line?*

Well you need to save them as they are entered:

```
int num;
var nums = new List<int>();

while (nums.Count < 10)
{
    Console.Write("Enter: ");
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
    {
        nums.Add(num);
        Console.Clear();
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", nums));
```

Comment: I dont know why, but it keeps showing me error on the if line..the whole line i wrote it myself, then i copied it i have no idea why :/

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
Console.ReadKey(true)
```

it reads a key from console and does not show it.

you can use this to read word from console without showing it

```
public static string ReadHiddenFromConsole()
{
    var word = new StringBuilder();
    while (true)
    {
        var i = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;
        }
        if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            if (word.Length > 0)
            {
                word.Remove(word.Length - 1, 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            word.Append(i.KeyChar);
            Console.Write("*");
        }
    }
    return word.ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1 answers question as asked. Note that when using you'll need to build up strings from characters and deal with new lines before parsing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int length = 10;
            int[] myNumbers = new int[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter number:" );
                myNumbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Clear();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Your numbers: {0}", string.Join(",", myNumbers));
        }
```

Comment: hey :) what does Convert.ToInt32 exactly do?

Comment: The command "Console.ReadLine()" knows to get a string from the user. The Convert.ToInt32 takes that string and convert it to a number... it is like int.Parse basically...
This code will cause error if user types a non number though...

Comment: okok thank you, and why cant myNumbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); work if i put only console.read and not console.readline? I mean it works but it allows me to enter only 5 numbers and then brings back a set of 10 numbers i didnt enter

Comment: Because Console.Read() is entirely different method, 
it reads key strikes.
When you click on a number it reads the keyboard key code of it, it will read whatever you pressed until enter one char at a time...

For fun look at this code:

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Keypressed code =  #{0}:", Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read()));
            }
        }